# Symfony 2.8.4 + BeSimpleSsoBundle + Jasig CAS Error

Tags: symfony, curl, cas, centos7

I have a problem with my application.

I use Symfony 2.8.4 and in vendors list I ave besimmple/sso-auth-bundle, in last version.

I have an application on an old centos server with php 5.3.3 which work, but with symfony 2.5, I have to upgrade symfony.

On dev plateform ( winw 10 + wamp 2.4) my application work : besimple can authanticate on my CAS server, no pb. But on my new server, centos 7, php 5.4.16 it doesn't work I got this exception :

```
 Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).

500 Internal Server Error - RequestException

Stack Trace

in vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Client/Curl.php at line 31   -
            $errorMsg = curl_error($this->lastCurl);
            $errorNo  = curl_errno($this->lastCurl);
            $e = new RequestException($errorMsg, $errorNo);
            $e->setRequest($request);
            throw $e;
```

I have an another application, GLPI on this server which use curl to, and it works.

I don't know what to do and I my application he's up to be in production.

I tried to change curl_opt in with CIPHER_LIST like that :

```
curl_setopt($this->lastCurl , CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256');
```

but I've got this error :

```
Cannot connect: SSL is disabled.

500 Internal Server Error - RequestException

Stack Trace

in vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Client/Curl.php at line 31   -
            $errorMsg = curl_error($this->lastCurl);
            $errorNo  = curl_errno($this->lastCurl);
            $e = new RequestException($errorMsg, $errorNo);
            $e->setRequest($request);
            throw $e;
```

Can you help me ?

PS : i'm trying to put the application on an other server, with debien to see if the problem comes with my distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

I was requesting the CAS server through an old pfsense reverse proxy. I updated the pfsesnse to the last version (2.3.2) and all it's ok now.

Don't forget tu use this config for BeSimpleSso :

```
be_simple.sso_auth.client.option.curlopt_ssl_version.value: 1
be_simple.sso_auth.client.option.curlopt_ssl_verifypeer.value: false
```